# How to use gsub in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string as

```
pid ="2006"
```

I want to replace the pid to [2]006. Currently I am tried using following

```
1.9.3p448 :001 > pid = "12345"
 => "12345" 
1.9.3p448 :002 >  pid[0]="[#{pid[0]}]"
 => "[1]" 
1.9.3p448 :003 > pid
 => "[1]2345"
```

I replace the first_character with [first_character].So that is my question how to do it using **gsub**.

And I have to use that pid for checking that the process is running or not so for this I am using following command.

```
ps aux | grep -e #{pid}
```

here -e is for regular repression so that my actual command looks like
`ps aux | grep -e [2]006`

Comment: Try to make the question clearer: what do you want to replace, what is the desired outcome?

Comment: If it is unclear.. we can close it.. without down-voting.. a lots..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `gsub`, but there is a better alternative: [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub). `sub` replaces only the first occurrence in the string.

```
pid = "12345"
pid.sub(/\d/) { |m| "[#{m}]" }
# => "[1]2345"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right why should I use gsb, if I want to just replace first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Why you bother changing small part of the string? 
You can just re-assign it:

```
pid = '2006'
# some code later
pid = '[1]006'# '2006' will be replaced by the new value, '[1]006'
```

`gsub` or other method operating on the string takes some time, sometimes it's easier/faster to just re-assign value instead of *messing* with it.

If you still insist on changing first digit in your `pid` you can use regexp:

```
pid = '2006'
pid.gsub /\A\d/, '*' 
# => "*006"
```

`\A` -> Matches beginning of string.
`\d` -> digit(0-9)

Substitute `'*'` with the new value of the part of your pid that has changed.

If you want replace more than one digit use `{}` or other operators([here is list of *repetition operators*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition):

```
pid.gsub /\A\d{3}/, '*'
#=> "*6"
```

In the above example, `2006` was replaced with `*`.

Comment: I tried with `pid.gsub /\A\d/, '[#{pid[0]}]'` but not working am I doing wrong?

Comment: @r15 You must use `""` instead of `''`, like this: `pid.gsub /\A\d/, "[#{pid[0]}]"`. String in `''` is not interpolated = it won't change `#{42}` will produce `#{42}` not `42`.